# Q: VSCode Open Recent Ctrl+R Shortcut Removed

Tags: visual-studio-code

During one of the many recent Insider builds removed the "Open Recent" ctrl+r keyboard shortcut. I would add it back manually but cannot find the actually VSCode workbench or whatever command. Does anyone know what happened to the shortcut or at least what the command is so I can remap it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the steps I would follow:

- Go to File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts
- Type `open recent`
- Under the list of settings you would be able to see your desired setting (Open Recent...)
- Change the key binding to what you like

[image: keyboard-settings]

I'm not sure why they have removed it from the insider builds, perhaps someone else can shed some light on it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I never realized that screen was there! The VSCode team just cranks out the features. I ended up just adding to my keybindings.json file.
`{
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.openRecent"
  }`

Comment: @dprice Yes, bascially this does the same thing as well. When you do any changes here, it will be saved in `keybindings.json` :)

Answer (score 3):

Undigging topic.
In my case I had to remove every `Ctrl+R XXX` key binding and leave only `open recent`Ctrl+R`.

File -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.
Search for `Ctrl+R` and remove all except `File: Open Recent`

Comment: Personally, I had to remove all shortcuts installed by the `yarn` extension.

Comment: there were npm and .net core shortcuts added by extensions that broke it for me.